# Trigger controller function when link is pressed laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to trigger a controller function when a link is pressed.

So.., this is the HTML

```
<a class="hollow button primary" href="{{ route('hire.worker', ['id' => $id]) }}"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Hire as Worker</a>
```

This is the route:

```
Route::post('/profile/{id}', [
'as' => 'hire.worker',
'uses' => 'ProfileController@hire'
]);
```

And this is the controller:

```
public function hire($id)
{
    $worker = New Worker;

    $worker->workerID = $id;

    $worker->save();
}
```

When I press the button, the page only refreshes, nothing is stored in the database, I also have few other routes so that may be the issue.

```
// Profile

Route::get('/profile/{id}', [
  'as' => 'display.profile',
  'uses' => 'ProfileController@index'
]);

Route::post('/profile/{id}', [
    'as' => 'display.profile',
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@store'
]);

Route::post('/profile/{id}', [
    'as' => 'hire.worker',
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@hire'
]);
```

Comment: Links use GET as the request method so `Route::post` is not correct. Also I doubt you want to declare the same route twice.

Comment: try `Route::get('/profile/{id}', [
'as' => 'hire.worker',
'uses' => 'ProfileController@hire'
]);`

Comment: @bassxzero ah yeah, it won't work, if I put get, it will call it since the page loads.
I am trying to call a function when the link is clicked..

Comment: so create a new route like `/profile/link/{id}` and change your html link to reflect the change.

Comment: @bassxzero yes but once I press the button it will also take me to that route... this means that I need to make a view for that route

Comment: at the end of the controller method redirect to whatever page you originally wanted to go.

Comment: @bassxzero it worked, thanks alot, you can leave  a reply so I can mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links use GET as the request method so Route::post is not correct.
Create a new route like the one below and at the end of the controller method redirect to whatever page you originally wanted to go.

`Route::get('/profile/link/{id}', [ 'as' => 'hire.worker', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@hire' ]);`